# How to make a div height set in pecentage expand with its content?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, height, fullscreen

I'm working on a layout with 100% height sections and have been struggling to make this sections expand with the content when necessary.

I've tried `height: auto; min-height: 100%;` but it doesn't work.

Here's a **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/davidxmartins/jt49a064/5/)**

Comment: Which browser are you using ? Do you need to satisfy compatibility with old browser like IE ?

Comment: min-height:xx% requires a parent with an height  set. idem for height:xx%; it requires a valid value or refernece else it is xx percent of nothing. using display:table, height will expand and can be set only on display:table- parent if only one row

Comment: @sebastienbarbier Well, my client wouldn't be happy if this doesn't work properly in all recent versions of modern browsers including tablets and phones. As far as IE it should support at lest from version 10 and 11. Thanks in advance...

Comment: @GCyrillus Wouldn't the parent in this case be html, body { height: 100%} ? The heights seam to work fine,  their expandability is the issue. Maybe I'm missing your point...

Comment: your mean height within a cell  did not work cause parent (row or table) had no height set :) . in css you have cascaded and height/min-height in % needs a parent reference to calculate ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
.wrapper { 
    height: 100vh; /* vh instead of % */
}
```

For some reason  - which I have no time to investigate further at this point - this solves it only if I reduce your markup to the relevant minimum, see the fiddle:

> https://jsfiddle.net/jt49a064/6/

This should serve you as a starting point to fix it yourself now.

Comment: For some reason that doesn't work in my project. Thanks all the same.

Comment: Even if **you** cannot make it work in *your project*, my fiddle proves that the suggested solution solves the **main** aspect of your problem. You should be willing to do some research on your own now to find out what styles on other elements in *your* code, contrasting to the *reduced* version of *your* code screws it up.

Comment: I did do my research and couldn't find difference between height:100vh and height:100% when html and body are also set to height:100%, in fact the 2nd seams to be more widely sported. I voted up your answer as it might be helpful to someone else but I can't accept it as I'm asking for a solution to the layout provided and your approach doesn't work in it as you well know. If there's a better way to code the layout I'm open to suggestions. I tried your approach with floating containers instead of display and still doesn't work. I only ask for help after spending days without finding a solution.

Answer (score 1):

try this in your css

```
display:inline-block;
```

Comment: I thought this would save my day, but although it makes the container stretch with the content it also causes overlapping between containers.

Answer (score 0):

does this work for you??to change it itself you need to use auto instead of %

```
    html, body { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
     height: 100%;
      color: white;
             }

       .wrapper { 
       width:auto;
        height: auto; 
        background: SkyBlue;
            }

       .container { 
        width: auto; 
        height: auto; 
        background: green;
           }

    .table {
     display: table;
      width: auto;
     height: auto;
            }

          .row {
          display: table-row;
            width: auto;
                 }
      .cell1, .cell2, .cell3 {
            display: table-cell;
            width: 33%;

              }
      .cell1 {
       background: blue;
              }
       .cell2 {
     background: red;
           }
    .cell3 {
    background: LightSalmon;
           }
```

Comment: Thanks, but no, the point is to have responsive 100% height sections.

Comment: u need all section of same size...you mean green,red,blue all of same size

Comment: What I need is exemplified in the Fiddle. I don't see how I can better explain it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use display: table; and table-row for you containers :

In the CSS for the parent write this :

```
display: parent;
```

For the children :

```
display: table-row;
```